# Does Averaging Always Increase Concentration?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be i.i.d zero-mean real random variables and $\epsilon>0$. Is there a simple argument that shows
$$\mathbb{P}(|X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n| > n\epsilon) \geq \mathbb{P}(|X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_m| > m\epsilon)$$
whenever $n<m$? The normal case says yes. Assuming $X_i$ has a finite first moment is fine with me.

Comment: Am I missing something in the Bernoulli case?  Suppose that the underlying variable is $\pm 1$ (each with probability $1/2$), $n=2$, $m=3$, and $\epsilon=0.001$.  Then the left hand side is $1/2$, but the right hand side is $1$.

Comment: @KevinP.Costello Great. Thank you! I intuited the Bernoulli case and clearly missed this. It does hold for Gaussians though I'm quite sure.

Comment: If you don't assume finite first, moment, then the standard Cauchy distribution is a counterexample.

Comment: $\ldots\,$and if you assume finite second moment, then Chebyshev's inequality shows the sequence of probabilities goes to $0,$ although I think showing that it's monotonic may take more than Chebyshev's inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered:

As was shown in the comments, this inequality doesn't hold in general. If the variables are $X_i=\pm1$ with probability $\frac12$ each, for $\epsilon\lt\frac13$ we have $\mathsf P(|X_1+X_2|\gt2\epsilon)=\frac12\lt1=\mathsf P(|X_1+X_2+X_3|\gt3\epsilon)$.